# Startup Application Preference, won't run Golang Executable

Tags: 18.04, startup, golang

Added the following to my Startup Application Preferences under 18.04.

`(cd /absolute/path/to/executable_dir && exec ./executable)`

The above command runs the executable no problem manually.
But it just won't run on startup.
What's the best way to debug this type of issue?